# Scala PartialFunction construction with different results

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I was trying to debug why some partial function composition were not working when I noticed that depending on how you instantiate the partial function you get different results.

When you're using the syntactic sugar method it all works as expected:

```
scala> val pf1:PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {case "a" => println("AAA")}
pf1: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val pf2:PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {case "b" => println("BBB")}
pf2: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val pf = pf1 orElse pf2
pf: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> pf("a")
AAA

scala> pf("b")
BBB
```

However, if you use the PartialFunction object it doesn't work anymore.

```
scala> val pf1 = PartialFunction[Any,Unit]{case "a" => println("AAA")}
pf1: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val pf2 = PartialFunction[Any,Unit]{case "b" => println("BBB")}
pf2: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val pf = pf1 orElse pf2
pf: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> pf("a")
AAA

scala> pf("b")
scala.MatchError: b (of class java.lang.String)
at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
```

Why is that? You usually grow to expect that the apply method of an Object behaves like the constructor of the Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others noted, `PartialFunction.apply` converts an ordinary function into a partial function.

The only reasonable way to do this, since the domain of the ordinary function is unknown (as far as `PartialFunction.apply` is concerned), is to create a partial function defined everywhere.

So when you write `PartialFunction[Any,Unit] { case "a" => println("AAA") }`, you're actually creating *two* partial functions: the one passed into the `apply` method and the one returned by the `apply` method. They're almost the same, except that the returned function is defined everywhere and not just at `"a"`.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says that the apply method of the Object converts an ordinary function to a partial one, but it does not detail how. Apparently it makes `isDefinedAt` to return `true` at all times:

```
scala> val pf1 = PartialFunction[Any,Unit]{case "a" => println("AAA")}
pf1: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> pf1.isDefinedAt("a")
res14: Boolean = true

scala> pf1.isDefinedAt("b")
res15: Boolean = true
```

This will result in the `pf1` always capturing the input. So I guess the conclusion is *be careful how you instantiate a partial function*.

Answer (score 0):

The apply method in the [PartialFunction Object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction%24) converts ordinary function to partial one. Read the documentation [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction%24) So the partial function that was declared is treated as an ordinary function and typed as PartialFunction. The domain for this function becomes all the domain of an ordinary function regardless of what is implemented there. So, pf1 ends up consuming all the input and never calling the orElse function.